# Is it safe to answer "erase disk and install Ubuntu" on a virtual machine?

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox

I am installing on VirtualBox on Mac. 
During install it asks: **Erase disk and install Ubuntu**

Question: Is it asking about the virtual disk - hopefully. Is it safe to answer OK?

Comment: Please consider accepting a answer below if it solves your problem.

Comment: I just did it myself and I thought the same thing. No worries, it will be perfectly fine.

Answer (score 64):

Assuming you are installing on a virtual machine that is running on your host OSX system, the VM has no access to your host's hardware. It is running on a virtual drive that you created for it.

So no, it will not affect your host and the Ubuntu installer has absolutely no knowledge of the host system. It is safe to answer OK.

Comment: And what happens when the disk space gets larger than the unused disk space, perhaps not at start, but later, when the usage grows e.g. to 40 out of 50 GB and your main drive has only 40 GB space left? In other words, will the VM ever overwrite data, or will it report this? Will the host just tell you that host space is limited due to that VM?

Comment: The installer tells me directly after the choice of the "Erase" option: `If you continue, the changes listed below will be written to the disks. Otherwise, you will be able to make further changes manually.  The partition tables of the following devices are changed: SCSI3 (0,0,0)(sda)  The following partitions are going to be formatted: partition #1 of SCSI3 (0,0,0)(sda) as ext4`. I have chosen "Continue" and nothing bad has happened :). It is probably because I have another VM already installed. I do not think that the VM will ever overwrite data of the host. If I am wrong, please comment.

Comment: @Lorenz the VM will never affect the host. When you install in a VM you are installing in a virtual disk that is only visible to the VM (it exists as a regular file on your host file system). If you fill up that "disk", then the VM might crash, but it won't affect the host system. That said, please don't ask questions in comments. If you have a new question, you can [ask it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) separately.

Comment: I have opened a small question on this [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1610655/can-a-vm-ever-overwrite-the-host-disk-or-a-host-ever-overwrite-a-guest-disk). Please answer there if you like.

Answer (score 9):

Yes just click erase disk and then follow the instructions. If you're running on a Virtual machine then it is always going to install to the virtual disk.