# Installing Ubuntu Problems

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, virtualbox

Currently trying to install ubuntu 14.04 through virtual box. I need this software to run ROS for school this year. everything seems to be going smoothly up until where it asks Installation type and i select "erase disk and install Ubuntu". I then receive the following notification :

[image]

I stop there since i do not want to risk losing anything. All my stuff for school is on my computer. What should I do?

EDIT : Thanks for the answer. Can someone just help address this concern: some user is claiming to have had his computer crash in a similar situation :

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=64425

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it safe to answer "erase disk and install Ubuntu" on a virtual machine?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/499894/is-it-safe-to-answer-erase-disk-and-install-ubuntu-on-a-virtual-machine)

Comment: Yes they are similar, however, i have an additional cause for concern , ( see edit in the question ). Also, other question makes no mention of the issue that comes up in the image link i posted. Thanks

Comment: You should back up your school work regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message is not specific to you. 
First of all this is not an error, this is a warning message made simply so that people are careful to not erase their disk if they don't want to. You however are installing this on a virtual machine. 
A virtual machine is like a separate computer inside your own computer, so it cannot erase the disk inside your actual computer. Not even if you tried, so you can safely press the Continue button

As for the computer crash, don't worry it seems to have been some specific issue with the virtualbox software so it probably will not affect you. He had an issue with the fact that he had some VM files on another partition on his actual fisical disc and that got messed up somehow.

If you follow the default options for Virtualbox, that will not hapen to you.

Comment: Thanks !!! New to all of  this so i figured better safe than sorry. Appreciate all the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing this within VirtualBox then you are fine to erase the disk since it is a virtual disk within VirtualBox only.