# Installing Ubuntu on a VM | Can anyone help with this warning?

Tags: system-installation

I am fairly new to Ubuntu but I must say first of all... **I LOVE IT!** I am going through all of the installation and setup for it, but when I get to the installation type screen that is where my worry started. The screen looks as follows:

This computer currently has no detected operating systems. What would you like to do?

## ⚪Erase disk and install Ubuntu

**Warning: This will delete all your programs, documents, photos, music and any other files in all operating systems**

Will this delete everything in my host machine?

Thanks in advance.

PS: My apologies for the awful formatting, this is my first time posting here as im sure you can tell.

Comment: See [Is it safe to answer “erase disk and install Ubuntu” on a virtual machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499894/is-it-safe-to-answer-erase-disk-and-install-ubuntu-on-a-virtual-machine) and related linked questions

Answer (score 0):

Unless you seriously misconfigured the VM, no, it will not.  I believe most VM's offer a simpler route to just get set up with an OS image: you might want to look into that.  In any case, VM's work to prevent even a malicious program from doing this, so the Ubuntu installer won't.