# install ubuntu on VM

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox

Hello I was trying to install ubuntu on my VM and when I got to the installation type I saw that everyone choose "erase disk and install ubuntu" but I wasn't sure what it is going to erase,     The whole dedicated disk I installed the VM on or the folder that located on the dedicated disk.
I saw that more people asked this question but I didn't understand the terms they used.
Thanks to everyone who answer

Comment: Go ahead and choose "erase disk and install ubuntu". It will install Ubuntu in the whole virtual image dedicated to the VM. In a real install (outside VM), that option would format the hard drive and install Ubuntu, but in a VM it is safe.

Comment: It affects only the assigned virtual drive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it safe to answer "erase disk and install Ubuntu" on a virtual machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499894/is-it-safe-to-answer-erase-disk-and-install-ubuntu-on-a-virtual-machine)

Comment: virtual folder means the folder on the dedicated disk that the VM located on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does "Erase Disk and Install Ubuntu" replace the default boot screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/552076/does-erase-disk-and-install-ubuntu-replace-the-default-boot-screen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will erase the whole dedicated Virtual VM Drive that you have created which is stored on your physical drive in some folder.

It is safe to do so , it will not affect your complete host physical drive but only will affect the folder where your Virtual VM Drive is stored